# numpy element-wise multiplication of an array and a vector

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to do something like this:

```
a =  # multi-dimensional numpy array
ares = # multi-dim array, same shape as a
a.shape
>>> (45, 72, 37, 24)  # the relevant point is that all dimension are different
v = # 1D numpy array, i.e. a vector
v.shape
>>> (37)  # note that v has the same length as the 3rd dimension of a
for i in range(37):
    ares[:,:,i,:] = a[:,:,i,:]*v[i]
```

I'm thinking there has to be a more compact way to do this with numpy, but I haven't figured it out.  I guess I could replicate v and then calculate `a*v`, but I am guessing there is something better than that too.  So I need to do element wise multiplication "over a given axis", so to speak.  Anyone know how I can do this?  Thanks.  (BTW, I did find a close duplicate question, but because of the nature of the OP's particular problem there, the discussion was very short and got tracked into other issues.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [automatically broadcast](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) the vector against the outermost axis of an array. So, you can [transpose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) the array to swap the axis you want to the outside, multiply, then transpose it back:

```
ares = (a.transpose(0,1,3,2) * v).transpose(0,1,3,2)
```

Comment: +1 This is probably the better way to implement a function with an `axis` argument. I would probably let `swap_axes` or `roll_axis` figure out the whole permutation of the axis, but either one ends up calling `transpose` anyway.

Comment: @Jaime: I tend to only use `swapaxes` when I have dynamic axes in a variable, but I think that's really just prejudice on my part; `np.swapaxes(a,3,2)` isn't any less readable or explicit than `a.transpose(0,1,3,2)`. As for `rollaxis`, it's a little less obvious how to reverse that one after you're done, but still not too hard to follow.

Comment: My own prejudice is that if I know all the axes beforehand, I would go with something like DSM's solution above. And if I don't know them, i.e. if I have to generate the whole thing dynamically, it is a pain to write out the whole transposition of the axes, so I'd use one of the other functions.

Comment: Oh, and another comment! Rather than transposing back after the operation, which leaves you with a non-contiguous array, I would do something like `ares = np.empty_like(a); ares_view = ares.transpose(0, 1, 3, 2); ares_view[:] = a.transpose(0, 1, 3, 2) * v`, which should leave the same result in `ares`, only contiguous.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the answers.  I got many more than I expected.  I need a solution for arrays with a variety of dimensions, not just 4, and this one seems to fit that bill the best.  Thanks to all, though!

Answer (score 7):

Here is one more:

```
b = a * v.reshape(-1, 1)
```

IMHO, this is more readable than `transpose`, `einsum` and maybe even `v[:, None]`, but pick the one that suits your style.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with Einstein summation notation using numpy's `einsum` function:

```
ares = np.einsum('ijkl,k->ijkl', a, v)
```

Comment: I like this.  Very elegant.  But it looks like einsum has a bit of a learning curve, and I need to get my project developed post haste.  Thanks much.  Will keep it in mind for the future.

Answer (score 4):

I tend to do something like

```
b = a * v[None, None, :, None]
```

where I think I'm officially supposed to write `np.newaxis` instead of `None`.

For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a0 = np.random.random((45,72,37,24))
>>> a = a0.copy()
>>> v = np.random.random(37)
>>> for i in range(len(v)):
...     a[:,:,i,:] *= v[i]
...     
>>> b = a0 * v[None,None,:,None]
>>> 
>>> np.allclose(a,b)
True
```

Comment: Actually `a * v[:, None]` is sufficient since it matches from the last axis forward.