# How can I multiply a column vector with a matrix element wise in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I have a numpy array **X** with shape (100,3) and a numpy array **sub_res** with shape (100,). How can I multiply **sub_res** element-wise with **X** so that I can get the resultant shape (100,3)? I want to avoid loop usage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [numpy element-wise multiplication of an array and a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388152/numpy-element-wise-multiplication-of-an-array-and-a-vector)

Answer (score 0):

You can transpose X and then multiply it by sub_res using numpy.dot and finally transpose the final result.

Comment: Your suggestion would produce a (3,) shape array.  The final transpose does nothing.  I try to illustrate my answers with a small working example.

Answer (score 0):

Make two arrays:

```
In [236]: X = np.ones((10,3)); sub=np.ones((10,))
```

Indexing with `None` (or `np.newaxis`) changes the shape of `sub`.  `sub.reshape(10,1)` would work just as well.

```
In [237]: sub[:,None].shape                                                                            
Out[237]: (10, 1)
```

By `broadcasting`, we can multiply a (N,3) with a (N,1) to produce a (N,3):

```
In [238]: (sub[:,None]*X).shape                                                                        
Out[238]: (10, 3)
```

You many need to (re)read some `numpy` basics, with focus on `broadcasting`.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html#broadcasting-rules