# Accelerate numpy calculation

Tags: python, numpy, math, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a Python function to integrate a vector field on a high-dimensional matrix space. `A`, shape `(n, m)`, is a matrix whose time derivative is linear in each of its components `A[i, j]`. We can collect all of the coefficients of the derivative into a 4D array `C` such that `C[i, j, k, l]` is the coefficient of `A[k, l]` in the derivative of `A[i, j]`. In this case, the derivative of `A` is given by `dA[i, j] == (C[i, j] * A).sum()`. Thus it is correct to compute

```
dA = np.array([[ (Cij * A).sum() for Cij in Ci ] for Ci in C ])
```

Fortunately, `C` can be represented as a [sparse.COO](https://sparse.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/sparse.COO.html) object so that the above requires only O(nm) multiplications. But the two for loops are still slow. Thanks to a helpful comment I improved this to

```
dA = (C * A).sum(axis=3).sum(axis=2)
```

leveraging broadcasting for a significant speedup. Can anyone go faster?

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388152/numpy-element-wise-multiplication-of-an-array-and-a-vector?

Comment: I hadn't seen that, but of course that works! That's a major speedup, I'll edit the post.

Comment: Can you provide an example of `C` and `A` matrix used? The speed of sparse matrices is very dependent of the input, especially the sparsity. The example can also be useful to benchmark the different approaches (for sake of reproducibility=.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [np.einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to accelerate this even more, as you won't have to do *any* intermediate calculations. Or at least you could do `(C * A).sum(axis=(2,3))` to remove one intermediate step.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.full((12,12), 2)
C = np.full((12,12,3,2), 1).T
dA = (C * A).sum(axis=3).sum(axis=2)
print(np.einsum('abkl,ijkl->ij', A[None, None], C) == dA)
print((C * A).sum(axis=(2,3)) == dA)
```

Output:

```
[[ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]]
[[ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]]
```

To be entirely honest, I don't completely understand your mathematical problem, and I am also not that good with `einsum`. That is, you should double-check that the algorithm and test case is correct :)

EDIT: Added `.sum(axis=(2,3))` method

Comment: Unfortunately ```einsum``` can't seem to handle the sparse array class I'm using for ```C```. The dimension is large enough that the sparse storage format is essential. But this is still a good thing to know about!

Comment: If anyone knows about an ```einsum``` alternative that works with any objects satisfying the ```np.ndarray``` interface, I'd be thrilled!

Comment: @FrankSeidl That's unfortunate, it would have been awesome if `einsum` worked. Anyways, I added another small optimization step that you could use, see my updated answer.

Comment: Ah of course. Thanks!